# Compare and working with multiple rows excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows

relatively new here..i am working with Excel VBA macros and managed to solve most of my problems, but i am stuck with one particular piece.

I would like to calculate the difference across rows.

Imagine a dataset with a, b, c, d, e rows and numerical values in the columns 1, 2, 3. i would like to calculate the differences between a1 and (b1, c1, d1, e1) AND the differences between b1 and (c1, d1, e1) AND the difference for c1 and (d1, e1) AND the difference between d1 and e1. And the same for columns 2, and 3.

I manage to make it run for a1 against all the other rows in column 1, but i couldnt figure out the loop for the other comparisons within column 1 and the jump to columns 2 and 3.

I hope someone can help!

Thank you so much!

Steve

---

```
Sub nABCXX()
Dim lastcol As Integer

lastcol = Cells(4, Columns.Count - 3).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 3 To Cells(3, Columns.Count - 3).End(xlToLeft).Column
For I = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(I + 1, j + lastcol + 5).Value = (Abs(Cells(x, j) - Cells(I + 1, j)))

Next I
Next j
Next x
```

End Sub

---

i see two major problems, first, the syntax above calculates the difference between row 4 and all other rows - not exactly what i want. 
But what i would like to calculate is the differences between all the rows in my table. One column would be enough, but column by column would be ideal.

The jump between the columns for a fixed calculation (only row 4) works just fine. But how to do it, when i have a multiple row comparison and multiple columns?

Thanks for your help!
Steve

Comment: Hi Welcome. Post what you currently have and specifically identify what part of it is lacking or is not working. Revise the question accordingly because as it is, it is off-topic.

Comment: Show what you current have and we will point you the direction. This is a good exercise to think about loops restricted by counters.

Answer (score 0):

While much too late for OP, noticed this pop up on my feed with no answers - so in case it helps anyone else...

Instead of the 3x *For Loops*, perhaps could use a *For Loop* with nested *Do While* loops.

So for example, imagining the table as something like

[image]

with header row/col, the numbers you are adding, and then the cells where you will write in the differences.

The macro could work as something like this:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer, EntryRow As Integer
Dim dbDiff As Double
```

First working out the total number of rows and columns to loop through

```
LastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Outer: this loop runs through the columns

```
For i = 2 To LastCol
    n = 2
    EntryRow = LastRow + 1
```

Inner: this loop changes the initial row to compare (i.e. 'a' row for a-b, a-c etc)

```
    Do While n < LastRow + 1
        m = n + 1
```

Innermost: this loop changes the row the initial row above is being compared to

```
        Do While m < LastRow + 1    'loops compare row n2
            dbDiff = Abs(Cells(n, i).Value - Cells(m, i))
            Cells(EntryRow, i).Value = dbDiff
            m = m + 1
            EntryRow = EntryRow + 1
            Loop
        n = n + 1
        Loop
    Next i
```

Maybe?